# Utilização do WordPress para deixar site gerenciável

Tags: wordpress

Trabalho com *frontend* e agora, quero realizar alguns trabalhos os quais eu possa deixar sites gerenciáveis para que os próprios usuários possam alimentar com o conteúdo.

Tenho alguns blogs/sites em WordPress e estava pensando em utilizá-lo. Tenho um conhecimento baixo em PHP, então, nesse início, creio que ele iria me ajudar.

Minha dúvida é: Tenho um layout em PSD, como posso me torná-lo utilizável para/no WordPress, por exemplo, deixando os campos editáveis? É preciso usar algum *framework* para WordPress?

Comment: O próprio WordPress já é um "framework" nesse sentido. Não precisa colocar nada em cima dele pra poder deixar os campos do seu PSD->HTML atualizáveis. Recomendo ler o Codex na parte de desenvolvimento de Temas: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: O título da pergunta estava incorreto. Porém, discordo dela ser ampla demais. Eu fui direto ao foco.

O @moraleida respondeu a minha pergunta corretamente. Ou seja, eu posso deixar o tema padrão do Wordpress e só editá-lo?

Comment: Pra mim, antes mesmo de ser considerado amplo eu diria que não está claro o que está sendo perguntado. a) Você quer saber se o WP pode ser usado como CMS multicolaborativo; b) Se você pode, e se sim como, usar um PSD próprio para estilizar o WP; c) Essa estilização vai ser aplicada ao portal público ou ao admin do WP;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é preciso colocar nenhum framework por cima do WordPress, você pode usar a própria estrutura dele para adicionar conteúdo a qualquer layout.

Você pode fazer isso de várias formas:

- [desenvolvendo o seu próprio tema](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
- [criando um Child Theme de um tema existente](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- ou usando um Starter Theme como o [Odin](http://wpod.in/), [Underscores](http://underscores.me/), [Thematic](http://thematictheme.com/), [Genesis](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/) ou outros

¹ eu pessoalmente nunca usei, mas se vc optar pelo Starter Theme, recomendo começar pelo Odin que foi desenvolvido por uma galera no Brasil e tem suporte em português.

Comment: Acredito que o ideal seja usar um Starter Theme também, muito obrigado, não sabia dessas informações! :P